# Windows CMD: How to pipe running program output to FINDSTR and write to file

Tags: command-line, cmd, pipe, findstr, windows-console

*I am trying to filter the output of a running program (ping) and write the results to a file.*

In the following example the ping program runs until CTRL-C is pressed:

```
ping www.google.com -t | findstr "Reply" >> file.txt
```

the result of this is the creation of 'file.txt' however, the contents are **empty**.

On the other hand, the following code, *without* piping to findstr works when interrupted with CTRL-C

```
ping www.google.com -t >> file.txt
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control the spelling of the findstr command is case sensitive you can use /I for disabled case sensitive and dot not use **double quote**

Parameter t does not allow redirection in a file because the pipe receive the result before do FINDSTR if using the n parameter file with the number of Reply wait the end of replay for see result file.

```
ping www.google.com -n 200 | findstr /I reply  >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

just try a `for` loop

```
@echo off
(for /l %%a in (0) do ping -t -n 1 www.google.com | findstr /i "reply")>file.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way I can write the output to the console?

Answer (score 0):

the file would be filled, when the piped command finishes. But `ping -t` will never finish. You have to build your own loop (which has some advantages...):

```
:loop
<nul set /p "=%time% " >>file.txt
ping -n 1 www.google.de|find /i "Reply" >>file.txt
ping -n 2 -w 500 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

the second `ping` is just a "500ms wait".

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of `ping`:

> -t: Ping the specified host until stopped.

Meaning it's waiting for user input to complete `ping` command.
The pipe on the other hand waited for input, and redirected whatever input was received to `file.txt` (*in this case no input was received because `ping` is waiting for user input to complete `ping` command, so a blank file was created*)

You can first redirect `ping` to file: 
`ping www.google.com -t >> file.txt`

Then when you have enough pings (via Ctrl-C), filter with `findstr`: 
`findstr "Reply" file.txt >> file2.txt`